# Tabs behind Keyboard - Android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an `TabActivity` (the tabs are at bottom) which consist of `EditText`, the problem is when I focus on the `EditText` and the **Keyboard** appears the tabs go above the keyboard which they leave me with small space above, Is there any way to prevent them to go above and let them be behind the **Keyboard**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute to your activity in the manifest :

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Just if you can explain what this attribute do and what other options it has (I'm trying to learn as much as I can about Android).

Comment: Look at the documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft